# AngularJS Load external template and controller from external file (GET)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a request to an HTML file where it should have all controllers it needs and the template associated to those controllers and then load them in a specific part of the webapp.

I can't make angular load the controller.. js works.. template gets rendered.. this is how I do it..

So the **external** file looks like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Hi'); // this alert works..
angular.module('testApp.externalControllers').controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    alert('Controller loaded'); // this alert doesn't
    $scope.textTest = 'Testing external controller text';
});
</script>

<div ng-controller='myCtrl' id='mainc'>
    {{textTest}}
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('testApp', [
    'testApp.controllers',
    'testApp.externalControllers',
    'testApp.directives',
    'testApp.services',
    'ngSanitize'
]);
angular.module('testApp.controllers', []);
angular.module('testApp.externalControllers', []);
angular.module('testApp.directives', []);
angular.module('testApp.services', []);

// ====================================================
// CONTROLLERS
// ====================================================

angular.module('testApp.controllers').controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
    '$rootElement',
    'TestService',
    '$timeout',
    '$sce',
    '$compile',
    function($scope, $rootElement, TestService, $timeout, $sce, $compile) {
        getExternalMiniApp(); // this starts the action

        function getExternalMiniApp() {
            TestService.getExternalMiniApp().then(function(success) {
                console.log('success getExternalMiniApp');
                console.log(success);
                var xmlString = success.data,
                    parser = new DOMParser(),
                    doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/html");

                // getting the <script> part
                var script = doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].innerHTML;

                // getting template that's inside div with id = mainc
                var template = doc.getElementById('mainc');

                console.log(script);
                console.log(template);
                var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
                var scriptTextNoFormat = script;
                var scriptText = document.createTextNode(scriptTextNoFormat);
                scriptTag.appendChild(scriptText);

                // append the <script> to the head, works..
                document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);

                // this is a div with id=foo where it should load the HTML 
                var whereTheExternalHTMLGoes = document.getElementById('foo');

                // set a timeout, I thought digest should take some time..
                $timeout(function() {
                    whereTheExternalHTMLGoes.appendChild($compile(template)($scope));
                }, 500);    

            }, function(error) {
                console.log('error getExternalMiniApp');
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        Test
        <div id="foo">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**TestService** only returns the `template.html` with an `$http.get`, very simple, no need to paste code I believe.

I'm successfully loading template and js, but can't make angular load the controller created in the `template.html` (external file).

This is the error I get: 
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/ng/areq?p0=myCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

I've tried with `appendChild`, with and without `$compile`, `ng-include`..

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Did you define ng-app="testApp" anywhere?

Comment: Yes sir I did, i'll edit and add the `index.html` to the question, it's very simple.

Comment: You can't load new modules after starting angular, all the modules scripts have to be loaded before you define you main angular module

Comment: No? I've read answers with lazy-load and requirejs, but those are not applicable to my problem I guess..

Comment: Using requrieJS is quite hacky, you can try using https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Comment: do you see any errors in console? can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: @Grundy it's all there in the question, the external file, and the code used and of course the error thrown... thank you. @fatman the problem here is that all the code is from an html file with `<script>` tags, I don't know if I can use what you gave me..